# Difference between @WebFilter and @ServletFilter

Tags: servlets, annotations

In JSP 3.0 API, did not find any references for **@ServletFilter**

does it Exist ????

What or How different is it from **@WebFilter**.

Online: https://blogs.oracle.com/swchan/entry/servlet_3_0_annotations

with regards
karthik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@ServletFilter` was replaced with `@WebFilter` in the [final draft](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=315) on the [specification](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr315/index.html).